# Java: read a file when it is updated

Tags: java, timertask, fileupdate

I wrote a code to read a file and update a database with is contents. I'm using timer task to do this process every 15 minutes. But I want to do this **at the exact time when the file is updated/changed**. Not every 15 minutes. I took a look for this but couldn't find something helpful. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java 7's [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to accomplish this for you. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)'s the official tutorial.

Comment: I think and hope this will give me what I want. Thank you.